# When lighting up specific LEDs in 8x8 matrix, a whole column won't turn off Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

The problem is that when I try to make a specific image, one column is lighting up without me asking it to.

The image that I want is:

```
_•____•_
_••__••_
••_••_••
•••__•••
••••••••
_••__••_
__••••__
```

But instead I get:

```
_•_•__•_
_•••_••_
••_••_••
••••_•••
••••••••
_•••_••_
__••••__
```

In fact, it won't turn off even if I fill the column with 0's or 1's.

After a little bit of trial and error I've found out that LEDs on this column light up in 2 cases:

1. The LED is supposed to be lit up
2. There is another LED lit up on the same row.

I am only learning the stuff. I got it like 3 days ago so I mostly copy and paste somebody else's code and rearrange it a bit to understand how all of it works.

This is the part of code that is responsible for this part of the program:

```cpp
// 2-dimensional array of row pin numbers:
int C[] = {2, 7, A5, 5, 13, A4, 12, A2};  
// 2-dimensional array of column pin numbers:
int R[] = {6, 11, 10, 3, A3, 4, 8, 9};    
unsigned char Mysia[8][8] = {
  0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
  0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
  1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,
  1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
  0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
};

void Display(unsigned char dat[8][8]) {  
  for(int c=0; c<8; c++) {  
    digitalWrite(C[c],LOW);
    for(int r=0; r<8; r++) {  
      digitalWrite(R[r], dat[r][c]);  
    }  
    delay(1);  
    Clear();  //Remove empty display light
  }  
}  
  
void Clear() {  
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {  
    digitalWrite(R[i],LOW);  
    digitalWrite(C[i],HIGH);  
  }  
}

void case2() {
  Display(Mysia);
}
```

Comment: Submit the code more completely

Comment: Have you checked it isn't a hardware/port config issue? You can check by reordering the entries in the column (and/or row) pin arrays. If the issue remains on the same column then I would suspect a hardware/port config issue.